# Remove all internal links from a bunch of .html files by Python string replacements

Tags: python, html

I'd like to remove all internal links from a bunch of .html files. The basic idea is that anything starting with `<a href=` is a link and if that does **not** start with `<a href="http` it's an internal link.

I'm trying to write a tiny Python script in order to accomplish this. Now the first half of each file gets done perfectly but it consistently crashes on the same link. I obviously checked for typos or missing `</a>`'s but I don't see any. If I rerun the script, the "problem link" gets removed but its `</a>` stays in. It seems more and more links get removed by rerunning the script but I'd like all internal links to be chopped out in one run.

Does anybody have a suggestion what I'm doing wrong? Please see below for the code I'm using.

```
tList = [r"D:\@work\projects_2013\@websites\pythonforspss\a44\@select-variables-having-pattern-in-names.html"]
for path in tList:
    readFil = open(path,"r")
    writeFil = open(path[:path.rfind("\\") +1] + "@" + path[path.rfind("\\") + 1:],"w")
    flag = 0
    for line in readFil:
        for ind in range(len(line)):
            if flag == 0:
                try:
                    if line[ind:ind + 8].lower() == '<a href=' and line[ind:ind + 13].lower() != '<a href="http':
                      flag = 1
                      sLine = line[ind:]
                      link = sLine[:sLine.find(">") + 1]
                      line = line.replace(link,"")
                      print link
                except:
                    pass
            if flag == 1:
                try:
                    if line[ind:ind + 4].lower() == '</a>':
                        flag = 0
                        line = line.replace('</a>',"")
                        print "</a>"
                except:
                    pass
        writeFil.write(line)
    readFil.close()
    writeFil.close()
```

Comment: Why not use a proper HTML parser instead?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I'm used to doing this kind of stuff with Python -although this particular example may be a bit beyond my basic skills. But what exactly do you suggest? There's some 80 files with an average of about 20 internal links each.

Comment: I'd use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) for this.

Answer (score 1):

Use an HTML parser like [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) or [lxml](http://lxml.de/). Using [lxml](http://lxml.de/), you might do something like this:

```
import lxml.html as LH

url = 'http://stackoverflow.com/q/15186769/190597'
doc = LH.parse(url)

# Save a copy of the original just to compare with the altered version, below
with open('/tmp/orig.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(LH.tostring(doc))

for atag in doc.xpath('//a[not(starts-with(@href,"http"))]'):
    parent = atag.getparent()
    parent.remove(atag)

with open('/tmp/altered.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(LH.tostring(doc))
```

---

The equivalent in [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) looks like this:

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib2

url = 'http://stackoverflow.com/q/15186769/190597'
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url))

with open('/tmp/orig.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(str(soup))

for atag in soup.find_all('a', {'href':True}):
    if not atag['href'].startswith('http'):
        atag.extract()

with open('/tmp/altered.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(str(soup))
```

Comment: I guess lxml is not exactly the biggest fan of MS Windows... This is getting too complicated. I'll just strip all links out and reenter the external ones manually. Thanks for your suggestions anyway!

Comment: Can you install BeautifulSoup?

Answer (score 0):

```
    query = input('Enter the word to be searched:')
url = 'https://google.com/search?q=' + query
request_result = req.get(url).text
soup = BS(request_result, 'lxml')
for link in soup.find_all('a', href= re.compile("https://")):
    print(link['href'].replace("/url?q=",""))
```

I have used the code above in Beautiful Soup and successful in returning the https links only.

I tried the solution posted above and it does not work for me in fact my links get reduced to great extent after using the code above.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](/tour)

Comment: This does provide answer to the question asked. This code will provide only links. and I just edited as I found the answer to my question

Comment: If it is the answer to your question please add it at your own question, not on this one. If you cannot turn this post into an answer to the question at the top of this page and according to [answer] then please delete it.